# passing info to django template images

Tags: django, django-templates

My images are named according to a profile parameter.

an example would be  - profile id 3423

the image would be http/path/imagebig3423.jpg

```
<img alt="" src="http://path/imagebig[profileid]" />
```

how do i pass that info to the template?

Comment: This really sounds like a designflaw in your object layer. Is there a reason your profile does not have a imagefield?

Comment: it's not the profile picture. it's an image that gets auto generated based on signup details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

views.py:

```
def some_view(request):
    # get the desire profile_id to pass to the template or set explicitly
    profile_id='3423'
    context = { 'profile_id':profile_id, }
    return render_to_response('some_template.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

some_template.html:

```
<img alt="" src="http://path/imagebig{{ profile_id }}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You normally pass a hash to the template, and you could put your template in that

Firstly, you might find it worth re-reading part 3 of the tutorial where it covers [getting started with templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/template-response/). Then look at the template docs [in detail](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/template-response/)

A code snipped would be something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
def detail(request, profile_id):
   p = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=profile_id)
   return render_to_response('profile/detail.html', {'profile': p})
```